# Combination of 60 people to 10 Station with 6 Slots and all that 10 Rounds

Tags: combinatorics

I need to associate 60 different names people (could be defined by 1-60) in 10 Stations that all have 6 Slots.
There they will have to do a task and then move on to the next Station.
This will be done 10 times so that in the end everybody has done every task.

The important part ist that

- everybody shall get to "met" every other person
- meeting another person twice over the course of 10 rounds should be avoided as best as possible

Mabye you can help me, since now no one could help me with this.

Best wishes
Lucien

Comment: You could use MiniZinc along the lines of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1830575/58610).

Comment: Yeah good idea but in the answer you linked they were also not able to have a solution for the question...

Comment: Try other MiniZinc solvers. Add constraints to break symmetries. Start with smaller parameters.

Comment: I have absolutely no experimente with coding, so thats not gonna work :/